# Copy file from raw folder to system/

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to copy a file from the RAW folder and copying it to `/system/`, I tried with both `Cp` and `Cat` with no luck with any of them, here's the code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    try 
    {
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o rw,remount /system");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cp /raw/test.ogg /system/test.png");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("mount -o ro,remount /system");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: system is a folder on the file system of your device.

Comment: raw is a folder on your development machine visible in the IDE. Files in it are packed into your apk and stay there.

Comment: @greenapps So how do I copy a file from there into the /system/ folder? That's still my concern

Comment: I have no idea.